# Filter Twitter Ampersand in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm using Tweetstream to grab twitter content that's useful for me, using the opener below to filter based on tweet content.  It works great 99% of the time, but sometimes I want to search Twitter for the ampersand character (&), and thats when everything goes wrong.

This filter is supposed to grab any instance of "word1", or "word2&word3"

I started out trying:

```
@client.track("word1", "word2&word3") do |status|
    my code in here
end
```

then tried

```
@client.track("word1", "word2&amp;word3") do |status|
    my code in here
end
```

and even tried

```
@client.track("word1", "word2%26amp%3bword3") do |status|
    my code in here
end

@client.track("word1", "%22word2%26amp%3bword3%22") do |status|
    my code in here
end
```

I've also noticed that it's very hard to search for the ampersand symbol on the twitter webpage - it seems to be ignored by the search bar.

Can somebody share how to effectively search for the ampersand symbol using Tweetstream (or any other Ruby gem/package)?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, but have you tried using an entity?  Like `&amp;` or `&#38;`

Comment: I've tried &amp; within the quotation marks, eg:  "word2&amp;word3" - just tried "word1&#38;word2" with no success

Comment: Using the `Twitter::Streaming::Client` from the `twitter` gem, this seems to pick up the `&` character in tweet text (which renders like `&amp;`): `@client.filter(track: '%26') { |tweet| puts tweet.text }`. Maybe you can play around with that to get your desired search term?

Comment: Thanks O-I, I tried to get the twitter streaming option running for about 4 hours to no avail (no luck in getting past the authentication in stream mode, everything works fine in REST).  I've thought of a couple of workarounds, but it seems odd that it's so hard to search for a phrase with an ampersand in it...  I guess if everything was easy, life wouldn't be so fun.

Comment: @ShawnyV Is what you are working on in a public repo? Hope you figure it out, and if you do, I'd love to know what you found.

Comment: Sorry for not coming back to this earlier - I'm not working on a public repo, this was just a personal project for fun.  Unfortunately I wasn't able to solve the problem, though I believe it's simply a matter of exact string matching not being offered by Twitter via the streaming API.  Somewhat off topic, I had a whole host of issues trying to implement Twitter vs. Tweetstream when it came to streaming, as well... But that's probably just cause I missed something obvious, haha.